# Highline ask method won't use same line

Tags: ruby, highline

Setup:

- Bash
- Ruby 1.9.2
- highline (1.6.13)

Description:

I'm fairly used to highline with some other projects, but haven't used it in a few months. Now, on a fresh install on Ruby 1.9.2, it doesn't seem to allow prompts to be answered on the same line.

So previously I would see something like:

```
 require "highline/import"
 ask "What is your favorite color?"
```

And get:

```
 What is your favorite color? |
```

Now I see something like:

```
 What is your favorite color?
 |
```

Where the pipe (|) symbol is my terminal cursor.

Any ideas why this change has occurred?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put a space at the end of the question string, eg

```
ask "What is your favorite color? "
```

Comment: The simplicity of that is embarrassing, but I can't say it's obvious. Thanks!

Comment: np - I agree it's not obvious, I had to read through the rdoc when I first used highline to find it.  But I can't remember it behaving different :)

Comment: it's likely that I was the one behaving differently... haha